# Jquery.cookies help needs

Tags: jquery, cookies

Totally newbie for the jQuery.cookies here.

So basically I got a site with a sub menu like below:

Main Site

```
- Sub Page 01
   --Zone 1
   --Zone 2
   --Zone 3
   --Zone 4
   --Zone 5
```

--Sub Page 02

--Sub Page 03

--Sub Page 04

All the page have the same contents, but different heading banner and text on top of the zone pages, and what I really need to do is:

- when visiter landed on the main page, it will show the main page heading, if the visiter click through Sub Page 02, 03, 04, the same heading image and text remain the same;
- when the visiter click to a zone, for example zone 1, the heading image and text will change to the zone 1 images and text, and from there if the visiter go to sub page 02, 03, 04, the heading image and text will remain the same which is the zone 1 heading image and text;
- Same as if the visiter go to Zone 2, 3 and 4, and the heading image and text will stats with what zone they clicked first and remains the same until they click another zone.

So what my question is, can this to be done by using jQuery.cookies? and how exactly done? If not is there any other way to make this happen?

Thanks guys it will be really helpful is someone can give me a direction.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think you need cookies here ?

Comment: Cookies doesn't seem like the right approach to me. I would do this by defining the site's structure hierarchy, using a scripting language (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc...) to add classes to the body tag, then using CSS to render the "correct" image. Are you using a CMS?

Comment: I don't know if you mean my cookies library or the other popular one, but I wouldn't use a client side cookies library for this. It would helpful to know what all the URLs look like for this system as I don't even think server side cookie management is best for this. If you were to use cookies, however, it seems best in this case to issues and react to the cookies server side.

Comment: @AlokSwain I was think use the cookies so that remember which zone the visiter clicked so that the top banner changed and remain the same when they go to other sub pages.

Comment: @JAAulde There is no url as I'm on the process of making the site structure and getting ideas to make it happens.

Comment: @jonathan.dh I'm using a CMS and it's .NET basic. Also not just image on the header banner, also there is text inside that div as well...

Comment: Then your CMS should provide a way to define menu hierarchy and sections. Use that to write a header module that prints out what you need depending on the section. Using cookies for this will certainly cause problems, e.g. if users have multiple tabs open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unaware of the exact CMS you are using here, so I will jot down a basic approach that I would have followed. 
Assuming your main page is like a landing page, then use a different layout for it. For the rest of the zones and sub-pages one could follow the below steps. (Although I do not know how well your CMS handles it).
If your Sub-pages are under the namespace of the zones then you could use a particular layout per namespace and render the contents of the subpages in that layout. This could ensure that whatever the subpage content it the header comes from the zone that you are in. There might be many other ways to do it, I guess if the routing of actions etc is handled by the CMS then you are better off finding a way to do it with options they provide as jonathan.dh said in his comment.

Comment: Thank you so much Alok, I did talk to the CMS guys and unfortunately there is no simple way to do that what we want.
And all they said the stupid way can be done is creak all the inner page with articles for each zone with the same content, or create the contents somewhere else and embed them into the inner pages for each zones pages. The problem is there are 100+ page for the main site, and we got 14 zones, that's 1400+ contents we have to create.... which I don't want to do that...

Comment: Way-1: This is basically what is done with rendering a common layout for a certain namespace and take the content to be shown inside they layout. The advantage one gets with being able to render things with a common layout is that you could modify your header separately and content separately. Otherwise with so many pages say one ever have to modify the header for a certain zone, this means when you have repetitive content shown for all the 100 sub pages inside a zone you will have to change it in 100 places, which is a great overkill.

Comment: Way-2: create the content somewhere and embed them inside the inner-pages- would help you prevent repeating the content of the header in all 100 sub-pages. You could use XHR to get the content for the sub-pages and then replace the html.

Comment: hi thanks again Alok for being such helpful :D
I worked out some options today:
Way-1: Kind of the same as your Way-2, to use jqueryloader to embed articles when needed.
Way-2: use CSS Switcher, I think this is the best option so far, so what I did is created all the zone header in different class id and only show the default one. Then by clicking the sub menu it change the css to display the matched header and hide the others...

For your way-1, which I though it will work couple days ago but sadly the CMS not allow us to do that...